# How do I create a QR code scanner that goes to a particular screen in my app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, qr-code

Im trying to build a Qr Code scanner into my app, But the way i want it to operate is... When a user scan a generated qr code it should go to a particular post on the app. of course, the generated qr code is for the post, but i dont want it to just show me the url, or data of the qr code, I want it to navigate to the page.

Something like how Expo opens your app when you use it to scan the qr code through expo.

Thanks

Comment: Does the user scan the QR code from within the app or from a third-party QR scanner? I think what you should be looking into is deep linking here.

Comment: Another approach is based on if you are using a third party QR scanner. Some libraries have an onScan/onRead callback that you can take advantage of to than do something in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Deeplinking](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/easy-deep-linking-with-react-native-and-expo-84e3c7b9d63e)

this link :

`instagram://` in iOS this will open instagram app